# How can I solve this integral for Fourier series?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to find the Fourier series expansion for $f(\theta)=\cos(\theta/2)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$. To solve for the coefficient, I'm trying

$$
c_k=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{-ik\theta}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}
$$
I got stuck on solving this integral. Any suggestions on how I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? [Fourier series for $\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581655/fourier-series-for-cos-frac-x2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with trig functions as in the hint, or with complex exponentials.
Or try both and check that the results agree!

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos \left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right) e^{-ik\theta} d\theta 
= 
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi  \left[e^{i\theta/2}+e^{-i\theta/2}\right] e^{-ik\theta} d\theta 
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi  \left[e^{i(1/2-k)\theta}+e^{-i(1/2+k)\theta}\right]  d\theta 
$$